How to import data an images created in Jupiter notebook
I attend classes in machine learning, we work with python in "Jupiter notebook". Since that program is not the best for work, I switched to Google colab. All available lectures are in ipynb format, with each lecture there is also a folder with images. The problem I have is that when I open the ipynb file in google colab, the images are not displayed, only the text and datasets.
my question is how to upload images along with ipynb file?
is there a way to load the file together with the images, or rather the folder where they are located so that the paths of images given in ipynb file are not changed?
thanks!
I have tried to upload photos in session storage
